# currentWindow: true not calling the correct tab using Chrome Extention

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

**Solved**
I had the wrong source unpacked files added...

With the script below i get the error:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot access contents of url "https://www.reddit.com/". Extension manifest must request permission to access this host.

**Script:**

```
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, (tabs) => {
        chrome.scripting.executeScript({
            target: { tabId: tabs[0].id },
            args: [VerCodeComplete],
            func: (VerCodeComplete) => {
                document.getElementById("subject").value = VerCodeComplete;
                document.getElementById("text").value = VerCodeComplete;
            },
        });
    });
```

I have used  `chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, (tabs) => {` in other locations within the .js without issues.

The way I understand this, the script is not trying to run in the correct window and tab.

If I only have one Chrome window open this works as expected, with more than one window, the error above appears.

Is there something obvious I missed?

---

Permissions from manifest:
`"permissions": ["tabs" , "scripting" , "activeTab"],`

---

These functions work as expected

```
//Change the language in KS from EN to NO

$("#Change_btn").click(function () {
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, (tabs) => {
        url = tabs[0].url.replace("en-US", "nb-NO");
        chrome.tabs.update({ url });
    });
});

//Change the language in KS from NO to EN

$("#Change_btn_en").click(function () {
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, (tabs) => {
        url = tabs[0].url.replace("nb-NO", "en-US");
        chrome.tabs.update({ url });
    });
});
```

The following does not work as expected

```
//Generate Email code Code_email_btn_en

function Code_email_en() {
    const generateRandomNumber = (min, max) => {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
    };
    var VerCodeEN = generateRandomNumber(111111, 999999);

    var VerCodeText = "Verification code: ";

    var VerCodeComplete = VerCodeText + VerCodeEN;

    //Auto-paste to Email
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, (tabs) => {
        chrome.scripting.executeScript({
            target: { tabId: tabs[0].id },
            args: [VerCodeComplete],
            func: (VerCodeComplete) => {
                document.getElementById("subject").value = VerCodeComplete;
                document.getElementById("text").value = VerCodeComplete;
            },
        });
    });
}
```

These are all in the same .js file, and functions are called from main .html document.

Language change script changes the URL as expected in the currently active window and tab.

The code generator works as long as there is only one Chrome window. With multiple chrome windows it does not call the actually active tab and window.

Comment: Is reddit the active tab? Does your manifest.json have `activeTab` in permissions or a matching pattern in host_permissions?

Comment: reddit was the active tab, but not in the active (focused) window, in the active window a different page was active. Added the permissions from the manifest in a edit to the post

Comment: Were does that code run? If it's the background script then this behavior may be correct depending on which window was last focused. You may want to use `lastFocusedWindow: true` instead of currentWindow because "[current](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#current-window)" doesn't mean "current foreground".

Comment: This does not run in the background script. This is a separate js. that is called from buttons in the main html file. I had no issues using activeTab for a different function in this js.

Comment: Please describe all the steps required to reproduce this behavior i.e. how and where that separate js runs, when, what is different to the case that works, etc. In other words, there's most likely nothing wrong with the API, the problem is caused by something else, and you'll have to find what triggers it.

Comment: permission: ["h ttps://www.reddit.com", ....]

Comment: Added detail to a edit below permissions. This is not designed to function with reddit, that is just the window it attempted to run the script on

Answer (score 0):

Cannot access contents of url "https://www.reddit.com/". Extension manifest must request permission to access this host.

So you need to add the url where you execute the script in your permission array in the manifest

permission: ["https://*", ...]

Comment: Thanks, but the issue it not with permissions, but with what tab and window the extension reads as active.